# How to display twitter videos in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, twitter

I have a small application that displays tweets. With this app I am trying to show twitter videos in a frame but as you know twitter doesn't allow to use iframe without it's widget javascript framework. For example I get

> refused to display in a frame because an ancestor violates

error when i use to access a video directly by iframe.

```
<iframe src="https://twitter.com/i/cards/tfw/v1/560070183650213889">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

[JSFiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/zcdpssmy/)

When i was trying to solve this problem i've started to think that whether breaking this security from client side is possible or not. If yes could you share the solution  with me.

If i use below codes, it works perfectly

```
<blockquote class="twitter-video" data-lang="en">
   <a href="https://twitter.com/OdunHerif/status/560070183650213889">April 10, 2016</a>
</blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The question is that can i do that without using twitter widget? How can i do it
[JSFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/d404mfjk/)

Answer (score 0):

Twitter videos cant display in iframe because of x-frame-options response header. You should use twitter javascript widget api like your JSFiddle 2